# Constraints autolayout for uitableview and uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I'm facing a constraints autolayout issue which is I have a UITableView at upper and UIView at lower. When the UITableView expand the tableView section, I want the UIView at the bottom shift down automatically, when collapse the tableView section, the UIView at bottom will move up automatically.

[image]

Below is my storyboard design, on the green sector is UITableView, on the red sector is UIView.

[image]

[You can get my code from here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3e7l6RGD-rnMmFDZi1LOS1MMkU)

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Cant you just make that UIView a part of your tableview (a cell or footer view) then it will shift with your other table view cell

Comment: @Tj3n Actually below still have some other UIView.

Comment: @NurII isn't it automatically adjusted when you add a row on the section (expanded)? as long as your bottom view's top is flushed on the tableview's bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the IBOutlet of height constraints of your tableview.

[image]

control + drag and drop to the view controller. You will get the property like this.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint * tableviewHeightConstraints;
```

Then call this one whenever you toggle the tableview. `contentSize` will calculate the tableview height and update the height to the `tableviewHeightConstraints` constraints.

```
CGFloat height = MIN(self.view.bounds.size.height, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
self.tableviewHeightConstraints.constant = height;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Err is that "@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint * tableviewHeightConstraints;" instead of "@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraints * tableviewHeightConstraints;" ?

Comment: Yes. Updated. Please check now. did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: Hi Bala, it got respond. But when I click the section expand & collapse. The result become opposite way. I've uploaded my code into this link, could you help me take a look? https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3e7l6RGD-rnMmFDZi1LOS1MMkU

Comment: Did you added `bottom constraint` for last subview to its superview which is below your tableview ?.

Comment: Remove that constraints and instead set the height of that view. So that when your tableview height increases, it will push all of your view below. If its goes out the screen, then will need to add scrollView. Otherwise you will see wierd thing.

Comment: Thanks Bala for your help, it work perfectly for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `ViewForHeaderSection`:
title1, title 2... is tableview header section. When expand `numberofRowinsection = 1` and = 0 when collapse - your uiview is uitableview cell in section.
Reload section when click section view.

Answer (score -2):

don't worry and be happy. I have make a solution for you. Just simple thinking about your Layout and flow the steep below:

1.Your parent layout is ConstraintLayout,
2.Secondly take a RelativeLayout,
3.Then take another ConstraintLayout and
4.Finally add your "ExpandableListView" and your UI element

You can also see the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#EACB3B"
    tools:context="com.example.uitableview.MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lvID"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="234dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/mango"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/expLv"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

                        <ExpandableListView
                            android:id="@+id/expLv"
                            android:layout_width="352dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Or you can also flow the Google Link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-yo9VvU7jyBUHN6RHVXQmUtVU0

Comment: But this is not iOS